# twitterbootstrap: layout help for beginner

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

How can one come up with layout for following page with twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm new to bootstrap and struggling with learning it by designing a live App. It's a page that you get after signing-in on www.dropbox.com

Comment: Which part specifically do you need help with? Or do you just not want to look at [the documentation?](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

Comment: I know documentation but for starters its difficult to solve problem that is bit different than mentioned in documentation. I was looking for whole page. how would one write this using bootstrap.

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails? If so, you may want to add that tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this series of [tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-introduction/) shall give you a solid start on how to use bootstrap.

If you are using RoR, Michaek Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial) is a very good book on RoR and he uses bootstrap in his example. So this tutorial should also give you some idea on how to use bootstrap with RoR.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start with one of the Bootstrap example templates? [This one](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html), for example, has a sidebar layout similar to what you are looking for. All you need to do is gut the `<div class="span9">` that contains the hero unit and the heading sections and fill it with your own content.

And, of course, read the documentation thoroughly and code up some throw-away web pages to help along the learning process.